# How to set up css hierarchies

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have links for the main class set to orange in my CSS, but, I want the read more link as white, and nothing I do is working.

OK, so here is the page setup:

```
<div class="entry_post">
<a href="http://localhost/" class="more-link">
Read More
</a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.entry_post a {
    color:#FF8800;
}
.entry_post .more-link a{
        color:#ffffff;
}
.more-link {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

I'm sure I am doing something wrong, but for the life of me i have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the tag and class selector (the tag selector is optional):

```
.entry_post a.more-link {
        color:#ffffff;
}
```

`.entry_post .more-link a` does not work because it means an `a` in a `.more-link` in a `.entry_post`. The problem with the simple `.more-link` is that `.entry_post a` is more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), so it will override it.

Comment: I do understand that this addresses the confusion in the incorrect `.more-link a` selector, but why would you need this? `.more-link {
        color:#ffffff;
}` should already match it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch `.more-link` does already match, but it loses to `.entry_post a` for specificity.

Comment: you will also want to cover that in your a:visited and a:hover rules if you want the link to stay white all the time

Comment: Knew it was just a simple issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

```
.entry_post .more-link a{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

This is incorrect: the above rule would match an anchor element (`a`) that's a *descendant* of an element with the `.more-link` class (which in turn is a decedent of the `.entry-post` class). What you want is:

```
.entry_post a.more-link {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Second, even though you already have `.more-link {color: #ffffff;}`, it's being overridden by `.entry_post a` (which is more specific), so it doesn't apply. But if you fix the first issue, you won't need to bother with this at all.

Comment: Just the same what I say, so +1 :)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
.entry_post a {
    color:#FF8800;
}
.entry_post .more-link {
        color:#ffffff !important;
```

}

You had some redundancies there

Comment: No need to use `!important` and override the default cascade. Just use  `.entry_post a.more-link` and it'll naturally take precedence.